# Command Python and others do not work in Windows 10 cmd

Tags: cmd, pip, path-variables

I am currently trying to install a Python library called "matplotlib" in order to make some plots of data, but I am having some issues while trying to install it.

I have install Python, add the Path of Python in order to use some commands in the cmd in Windows 10 Home and what I have found is that when using

```
"python"
```

the cmd shows it is not recognize, but when using

```
"py"
```

it shows

```
"Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32"
```

It would not be a problem if it was the only one. I tried also to install pip with
    "py -m pip install -U pip"
and the command gives the following answer:
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python36-32\lib\site-packages
As I undertand that means that I have already installed pip, why I cannot use it in the windows cmd?

My path variables in Windows include that:

```
C:\Python36-32;C:\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages;C:\Python36-32\Scripts
```

But when I do the following:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

the cmd does not recognize the command.
Do I need to add another variable system path in order to use "pip" and "python" in the cmd?

PD: I am currently using python to compile programs with Eclipse and it works fine

Comment: okay... Is asking for a solution and finding a possible solution in 3 minutes... I did  >py -m pip install matplotlib     in the cmd and it installed the matplotlib. Nonetheless it would be nice to know why is not >pip and >python commands working

Comment: Type `dir C:\Python36-32\*.exe /s` and see what directories have the executables you are interested in. Then add them to the path.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to write the directories separated instead of all in the same line as I saw on internet. Now it works perfectly.